# Problem in Date calculation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am using the below code to convert a string to a date.

I pass this "2010-06-23 00:00:00.0" as the input to the function. Instead of returning 21-June-2010 as the date, it returns me 21-Jul-2010. What could be the problem?

```
function getDateFromString(string){
var month = string.substring(5,7);
var day = string.substring(8,10);
var year = string.substring(0,4);
var dateValue = new Date(year,month,day);
dateFormat(dateValue, "yyyy-mm-dd");
return date;
}
```

Comment: Dates are 0-based.  So 06 is actually the 7th month of the year.

Comment: basically what everyone has responded with =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The months are numbered from zero, not one. In other words, "6" is July, not June.

(I mean, they're numbered that way as far as the JavaScript "Date" class is concerned.)

Answer (score 1):

The month has to be the actual month -1. You can find some examples at [Date - MDC Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in the section "Example: Several ways to assign dates" for example.

Edit: Changed link to MDC Docs after Bernhard Hofmann's suggestion.

Comment: Oh Dan - now what do I do? +1 for month offset, but -1 for referencing w3cSchool :p  Please use MDC Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

The `month` parameter of the `Date()` object constructor is zero-based.

```
var dateValue = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using substring which takes **from** and **to** as params. so basically you're always getting 3 characters with substring. (year even 5 chars)

```
var month = parseInt(string.substr(5,2));
var day = parseInt(string.substr(8,2));
var year = parseInt(string.substr(0,4));
```